# how to create a button in javafx that will only be visible after user clicks some other button?

Tags: javafx

What i mean is, suppose on my current scene there appears a 'login" button. When the user will click the login button the same scene will appear but with a new button named "browse". Basically i want to keep the "browse" button hidden until user clicks "login" button.

Comment: Use the `setVisible` property? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setVisible-boolean-

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`setVisible()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setVisible-boolean-) as stated by @Idos. You need to initially set the visibility of the Browse button to `false` and on the action of `Login` button toggle the visibility to `true`.

Here is a MCVE to help you understand how it works:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button login = new Button("Login");
        Button browse = new Button("Browse");
        browse.setVisible(false);

        login.setOnAction(e -> browse.setVisible(true));

        VBox root = new VBox(10, login, browse);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```